# Job scheduler - how to run an activity in background without launching application

Tags: android, firebase-notifications

I have just created an Android app for delivery boy ,In that admin can assign a duty to him through server.

The problem is that i want a functionality in which app can automatically sends the latitude and longitude to the server every 5 minutes of interval, I had used job scheduler but it is only works in my older phone which is Android Lollipop, it is not working in Android Nougat.

### MyService.java

```
package com.example.dell.firebase;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobParameters;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobService;

/**
 * Created by DELL on 3/20/2019.
 */

public class MyService extends JobService{
    BackgroundTask ba;
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters job) {

        ba=new BackgroundTask(){
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hello all "+s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("dd","hg");
                jobFinished(job,false);
            }
        };

        ba.execute();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
        return true;
    }
    public static class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
    {




        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            return "hello from background";
        }
    }

}
```

### My Xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.dell.firebase.MainActivity">   

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"

    android:onClick="startjob"
    android:text="start" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:onClick="stopjob"
    android:text="stop" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

## MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.dell.firebase;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.Constraint;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.FirebaseJobDispatcher;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayDriver;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.Job;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.Lifetime;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.RetryStrategy;
import com.firebase.jobdispatcher.Trigger;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String jobtag="Mytag";
    private FirebaseJobDispatcher jobDispatcher;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        jobDispatcher=new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));

    }

    public void startjob(View view) {
        Job job=jobDispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(MyService.class)
                .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                .setRecurring(true)
                .setTag(jobtag)
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(10,15))
                .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
                .setReplaceCurrent(false)
                .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
                .build();
        jobDispatcher.mustSchedule(job);
        Toast.makeText(this,"job Scheduled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void stopjob(View view) {
        jobDispatcher.cancelAll();
        Toast.makeText(this,"job Canceled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Without your code, no idea what's wrong.  However if their phone goes screen off, you're probably dealing with Doze mode, that prevents an app from having more than 1 window to do work every 15 minutes or so as a battery saving measure when the screen is off.  You can get whitelisted from Doze, but the user has to do it.

Comment: Actually i made simple log.d() in my job scheduler to check their working but when my app gets opened or remain on memory then it print the values in logcat as soon as when i jst removed it from memory it get stopped. It works fine in lolipop even after removing but fails in nogut and higher version

Comment: And Thanks fr ur answer i will post my code